# List Item Counts as a separate List Item?

Tags: list, workflow, dropdown

I'm trying to create a scoreboard, of sorts, and I'm having quite a time making it work like I want. Here's the situation:

In my primary list, each Representative puts an item into the list for their sales (each item representing a sale).  The item contains details of the sale, of course.  Once the item is in the list, the Manager can go into that item and choose from a DDL if the item is "Approved" by them or not.  (There are other DDL options, but I won't go into those right now.)  What I'd like to do is create a separate list that will display the Representative and their COUNT of records that they have where DDL=Approved.  I've tried using a workflow to approach this, but I can't seem to find any options for COUNTs like I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello @DanJ , Your feedback is very important 1. Are the below answers didn't helped you? 2. do you need any further clarifications? if yes, please comment to the provided answers with your clarifications to can help you or edit your question with these clarifications, else please upvote and mark the correct answer that helped you as accepted to **close this question.** Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In my opinion,** No need to create a sperate list with a complex workflow to achieve your requirements,

**What I recommend is to do the following:**

- Create a **Custom View** that **filtered** by `DDL=Approved`

[image]

- In **Totals** setting, beside any fields select `Count`

[image]

I think the above solution should match your requirement in an efficient and simple way :)

Comment: Forgive me, but wouldn't he then also need to create a filter for each Representative?

Comment: Hello @C.Dennett, you are welcome at any time, but he said "Representative puts an item into the list for their sales" so the representative, in this case, is a SharePoint user so you can only add an additional filter with created by = [ME] :) what about your opinion?

Comment: Oh, silly me I had completely failed to consider the =[Me] filter. Good point, sir! :)

Answer (score 2):

For this example, I created two lists; **Representatives** and **Sales**.

In Representatives, I have a column for the Rep's name, a UniqueID (how you choose to address this part is up to you... I just manually assigned a number), and a Count (or Score) of their Approved Sales. So:

**Columns**

- Name
- UniqueID
- Count

In Sales, I have a column for the Representative, the Approval DD (with just the two relevant options: Approved and Denied), and a column for the Rep's UniqueID (I called it RepID in the Sales List, and again for this example I just keyed them in manually, matching what I set up for the fictional Rep's). A Unique Identifier of some kind is important for this to work properly (especially if any Rep's have the same first and/or last name). So:

**Columns**

- Title (of the Sale)
- Approval
- Representative
- RepID

My workflow is set up as follows:

- First, I check the Approval status. If it's not Approved, I do
  nothing.
- If it is Approved though, I set a workflow variable to the Rep's current Count in the Representatives List. I created the variable, and called it RepScoreCurrent. To do this, I set up the Action as follows:

**Field Data to Retrieve**

- Data Source: Representatives (List)
- Field from source: Count (column)
- Return field as: As Integer

**Find the List Item**

- Field: UniqueID
- Value: Current Item: RepID

These bottom two conditions are what makes the workflow get the correct number. It will search the Representatives List, and retrieve the Count value from the item where the UniqueID column matches the RepID from the current Sales List item.

- Next, I do the "Do a Calculation" Action, and calculate Variable: RepScoreCurrent plus 1 (Output to Variable: calc). Note, you don't have to create the "calc" variable, as SP will do it for you.
- Finally, I choose the "Update List Item" Action, and set it up as follows:

**List:** Representatives

(skip the middle box for now)

**Find the List Item**

- Field: UniqueID
- Value: Current Item: RepID

Click the "Add..." button, and choose "Count" as the field, and Workflow Variable "calc" as the Value.

I hope this helps, and here are some screenshots of the whole setup:

**Sales List**

[image: Sales List]

**Representatives List**

[image: Representatives List]

**Workflow Overview**

[image: Workflow Overview]

**Setting variable to current Score**

[image: Getting Current Score]

**Updating correct Representative's Score**

[image]